# Using cython .pxd files to Augment pure python files

Tags: python, cython

Following the example here, "[Augementing .pxd](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/pure.html?highlight=pxd#augmenting-pxd)", I'm trying to use ".pxd" files to augment a pure python file. (Add type definitions external to the pure python file).

python file:

```
class A(object):
    def foo(self, i=3, x=None):
        print "Big" if i > 1000 else "Small"
```

pxd file:

```
cdef class A:
    cpdef foo(self, int i, x)
```

I've got a dictionary, which I'm defaulting to "None" in python.
Unfortunately, cython doesn't like this.

If I use my "pure" python file, without declaring a type or declare the type as "dict" in the pxd file I get the error:

> *"Signature not compatible with previous declaration"*

I noticed that it will compile if I do NOT specify a default value, but there's a reason for declaring the defaults.

Is there a way this can be handled?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Optional arguments in cpdef functions are declared differently from cdef functions which essentially is same as python functions.

Your .pxd file should be modified to be written as

```
cdef class A:
    cpdef foo(self, int i=*, x=*)
```

Comment: Thanks now I've got that working.  The next problem is __init__ method def in the pxd file...